# NoSuchMethodError : The getter 'docs' was called on null when trying to fetch a specific document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to build a tracking app using Google map and Firebase.
While trying to fetch data from a specific document, I am having this error. I think it occurs because there is no such document in my firebase. In that case I would love to show a message like "Not Available" or something, and catch the error.
I am still learning Flutter and I am having hard time figuring out how to get this done.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('location').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (_added) {
        mymap(snapshot);
      }
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      return GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: {
          Marker(
              position: LatLng(
                snapshot.data!.docs.singleWhere(
                    (element) => element.id == widget.user_id)['latitude'],
                snapshot.data!.docs.singleWhere(
                    (element) => element.id == widget.user_id)['longitude'],
              ),
              markerId: MarkerId('id'),
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
                  BitmapDescriptor.hueMagenta)),
        },
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(
              snapshot.data!.docs.singleWhere(
                  (element) => element.id == widget.user_id)['latitude'],
              snapshot.data!.docs.singleWhere(
                  (element) => element.id == widget.user_id)['longitude'],
            ),
            zoom: 14.47),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          setState(() {
            _controller = controller;
            _added = true;
          });
        },
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: You may refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57439587/catching-errors-in-flutter-firebase-auth-sign-up) and the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/error-handling/) containing how to catch errors in Firebase Flutter.

Comment: @MousumiRoy I tried if-else case that if the snapshot hasNoData it will return a message, but it seems like it doesn't really work. I might have made some mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for ur response btw. The documentation reflects mostly on the authentication error handling :(